# jQuery Datetime picker: bind custom array of years

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have custom list of years (e.g 1970, 1984, 1995, 2010) which i need to display it in jQuery Datetime picker.

From documentation it seems like we can specify a year range..is there any way i can bind my custom array of years to the datetime picker ?

Comment: Are you referring to the jQuery UI Datepicker widget (http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) or a different jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there is no built in support for this.

I would suggest your best bet would be to tie into the "beforeShowDay" event (probably for the first call as it gets called multiple times) as the year dropdown should have been added by this point.

From there you should be able to find the years dropdown and remove the years that you don't want.